# How to access /dev/mem in OSX?

Tags: macos, command-line, kernel, virtual-memory

How I can access /dev/mem (or /dev/kmem, /dev/pmap) equivalent device in OSX?

As far as I know it was removed in some point.

Can I create this node manually somehow or any other way of dumping the physical memory?

See:

- [Visualization in testing a volatile memory forensic tool](http://www.dfrws.org/2011/proceedings/10-342.pdf)
- [Kernel Debug Kit OS X](https://developer.apple.com/hardwaredrivers/download/kerneldebugkits.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to [Accessing Kernel Memory on the x86 Version of Mac OS X](http://www.osxbook.com/book/bonus/chapter8/kma/), `/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem` were removed when Apple released OS X for Intel processors.

The (excellent) article also explains **how to reenable the memory devices**, namely using the `kmem=1` kernel boot argument.

Note that, as commented below by [neal](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/355816/neal), **in macOS 10.15 Catalina (and probably since macOS 10.12 Sierra), NVRAM settings can only be changed when your Mac is booted into recovery mode**. To enter [Recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201314), power on your Mac and immediately hold <kbd>⌘</kbd>-R until the logo appears, launch Terminal from the Utilities menu in the menu bar, run:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="kmem=1"
```

and reboot. You should see these two devices:

```
$ ls -l /dev/*mem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 3, 1 2014-02-28 22:09 /dev/kmem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 3, 0 2014-02-28 22:09 /dev/mem
```

(In previous versions of macOS like OS X Mavericks 10.9.2, you can reenable the memory devices within the operating system, so simply launch Terminal, type the command above and reboot.)

**If your Mac won't boot or you have any issues**, reset the NVRAM by pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>P</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> and holding the keys down until you hear the startup sound for the second time, as explained in "Resetting NVRAM / PRAM" in [KB HT1379 About NVRAM and PRAM](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US).

If you wish to reset the argument, type `sudo nvram -d boot-args` and check that `nvram -p | grep boot-args` does not print any results.

Comment: I've tried this method in macOS Sierra, but it didn't make the devices show up under `/dev` .. perhaps do you know if Apple closed this option, and whether there's another alternative to access this memory in 10.12 ?

Comment: At some point, nvram settings could only be changed when your Mac was booted into recovery mode. So if you power on your Mac, and immediately hold Cmd-R until the logo appears, then drop to a Terminal from the Recovery installation UI and run the command, it should work. This just worked for me on OS X Catalina yesterday.

Answer (score 4):

I think I got it to work on macOS Sierra! I downloaded comex's project:
[Kmem Project](https://github.com/comex/Kmem)
I compiled the kext, fixed the permissions and then loaded it!
Using terminal I went into `/dev` and `ls` showed both `mem` and `kmem`...

Edit: If you download the project you will just need to change the compiler in Xcode to use the latest ( for example... I don't know if other versions work though... )  For quick access to results I have already made a fork of comex's project which compiles on macOS Sierra! [Kmem for Sierra Fork](https://github.com/npyl/Kmem)

Again, this is comex's work, not mine, I just changed the compiler setting and uploaded it! :)